# Linux & Windows: Is there a way to force SO/DLL to unload from memory

Tags: linux, windows, dll, shared-libraries

So we are working with SO and DLL files. After the `dlclose()` / `FreeLibrary()` the SO/DLL remains in the memory, which is a problem, because in the future the SO/DLL file may be updated, and after a second `dlopen()` / `LoadLibrary()` the older version is cached in the process's memory. On Windows it's a far bigger problem, because the .DLL file cannot be removed while the process is running.

On Linux our problem is solved with GCC's `-fno-gnu-unique` option, it works well. Our problem is, we don't want to rely on how the SO is compiled, mainly because we are not the team who writes SO/DLL files for our product, we just using these libs. Is it possible to unload a SO in a "forced way"? I mean, we should not be rely on if the SO is compiled with `-fno-gnu-unique` or not. I also investigated how the .SO file is mapped into the process memory map (`/proc/pid/maps`), unfortunately unmapping the .SO from the process not working.

On Windows I was not able to solve this problem. `FreeLibrary()` returns `OK`, but `GetModuleHandle()` says the DLL still present in memory. I'm also sure there are no references to the DLL, every pointer is set to `nullptr` when no longer needed. I tied to `UnmapViewOfFile()` the handle, and I'm able to delete the .DLL before the process finishes! But my process crashes at program exit or if I try to `LoadLibrary()` again.

Many questions on Stackoverflow/etc is about this, but I'm just isn't able to understand, why on earth can't we force an SO/DLL to be cleaned from a process. The basic answer is told in GCC's `-fno-gnu-unique` option: because `STB_GNU_UNIQUE` objects should be exist until the termination of the program. On Linux, I can override this behaviour with `-fno-gnu-unique`. I'm curious, why is this not possible on Windows (using MS Visual Studio compiler)? I also read a comment elsewhere "DLLs are not meant to be unloaded", but I'd like to know **why**.

Thank you.

**Example**

Here's a minimal example:

DLL:

```cpp
class Writer
{
public:
    Writer(int i) { std::cout << "Writer ctor" << std::endl; this->i = i; }
    ~Writer() { std::cout << "Writer dtor" << std::endl; }
    int get() { return i; }
    void set(int i) { this->i = i; }

private:
    int i;
};

std::thread* WorkerThread;

void proc()
{
    while (true)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
        std::cout << "DLL: I'm alive" << std::endl;
    }
}

inline void __cdecl function()
{
    static Writer w(1);
    std::cout << "i=" << w.get() << std::endl;
    w.set(w.get() + 1);

    if (WorkerThread == nullptr)
    {
        WorkerThread = new std::thread(proc);
    }
}
```

user:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <libloaderapi.h>

typedef void (__cdecl* function_type)();

int main()
{
    while (1)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter to continue...";
        getchar();

        function_type function;
        HINSTANCE dll_handler;

        dll_handler = LoadLibraryA("power.dll");
        if (dll_handler == NULL)
        {
            std::cout << "Error: Unable to load dll" << std::endl;
            continue;
        }

        if ((function = (function_type)GetProcAddress(dll_handler, "function")) == NULL)
        {
            std::cout << "Error: Unable to find function 'initialize' entry point in dll" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            function();
            std::cout << "function() returned " << std::endl;
        }

        std::cout << "Enter to FreeLibrary()...";
        getchar();
        int res = FreeLibrary(dll_handler);
        if (res == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "FreeLibrary() failed" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "FreeLibrary() succeed" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I compiled on Windows 10 with Visual Studio 16.

A typical output:

```
Enter to continue...
Writer ctor
i=1
function() returned
Enter to FreeLibrary()...DLL: I'm alive
DLL: I'm alive
DLL: I'm alive

FreeLibrary() succeed
Enter to continue...DLL: I'm alive
DLL: I'm alive
DLL: I'm alive
DLL: I'm alive
DLL: I'm alive
DLL: I'm alive
DLL: I'm alive
DLL: I'm alive
DLL: I'm alive
DLL: I'm alive
DLL: I'm alive
DLL: I'm alive
DLL: I'm alive
DLL: I'm alive

i=2
function() returned
Enter to FreeLibrary()...DLL: I'm alive
DLL: I'm alive
DLL: I'm alive
DLL: I'm alive
DLL: I'm alive
DLL: I'm alive
DLL: I'm alive
DLL: I'm alive

FreeLibrary() succeed
Enter to continue...DLL: I'm alive
DLL: I'm alive

i=3
function() returned
Enter to FreeLibrary()...DLL: I'm alive
DLL: I'm alive
DLL: I'm alive

FreeLibrary() succeed
Enter to continue...DLL: I'm alive

i=4
function() returned
Enter to FreeLibrary()...DLL: I'm alive
DLL: I'm alive
FreeLibrary() succeed
Enter to continue...Writer dtor
^C
```

The DLL starts a thread, and the thread won't stop. After "FreeLibrary() succeed", `power.dll` cannot be deleted as used by `power_main.exe`, but the program is waiting before the next `LoadLibrary()`, so in theory, the DLL should be deletable.

The `static Writer` object with the inrementing `i=` printouts shows that this object isn't freed when calling `FreeLibrary()`.

I would like to achieve to kill threads started by the DLL and clear the DLL from the program's memory when calling `FreeLibrary()`. Of course a good programmer wouldn't like the idea to forcefully stop a thread because it may holds resources and/or leave its state in a inconsistent way.

Our problem is that our program cannot delete the DLL file after `FreeLibrary()` because the DLL programmed in a "bad" way. As I said before, other development team develops the DLLs we load, and to be honest, we don't care if the DLL's stuff remains in an inconsistent way because of other development team's programming error, so we would like to forcefully clear the DLL from our program as I described above. What do you think, is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question with the updated code, not a link.

Answer (score 2):

This example works correctly on my system.  I think you have a reference count issue somewhere.  You can see from the output that the DLL did unload and switch to the second copy and they were even loaded to the same address.

test1.c

```c
__declspec(dllexport) const char* func(void) { return "foo"; }
```

test2.c

```c
__declspec(dllexport) const char* func(void) { return "bar"; }
```

test.c

```c
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef char* (*FUNC)(void);

int main() {
    FUNC f;
    HMODULE h;
    BOOL result;

    result = CopyFile("test1.dll", "test.dll", FALSE);
    printf("Copyfile %d\n", result);
    h = LoadLibrary("test.dll");
    printf("h = %p\n", h);
    f = (FUNC)GetProcAddress(h, "func");
    printf("%s\n", f());
    result = FreeLibrary(h);
    printf("FreeLibrary %d\n", result);

    result = CopyFile("test2.dll", "test.dll", FALSE);
    printf("Copyfile %d\n", result);
    h = LoadLibrary("test.dll");
    printf("h = %p\n", h);
    f = (FUNC)GetProcAddress(h, "func");
    printf("%s\n", f());
    result = FreeLibrary(h);
    printf("FreeLibrary %d\n", result);
}
```

Output:

```
Copyfile 1
h = 00007FFD53890000
foo
FreeLibrary 1
Copyfile 1
h = 00007FFD53890000
bar
FreeLibrary 1
```

##### EDIT per minimal example provided

The OP's DLL has a running thread when trying to unload.  The running thread holds a reference.  The process would crash if unloaded on a running thread (and does, if you call `FreeLibrary` one more time).

The following even more minimal code demonstrates that if you stop the thread, it works.  Comment out the `stop()` call to see that the DLL fails to unload. This makes sense.  `LoadLibrary` calls `DllMain` with `THREAD_ATTACH`, `FreeLibrary` calls `DllMain` with `THREAD_DETACH` and so will starting and stopping a new thread.  It appears Windows is reference counting the number of threads attached to a DLL.

**power.cpp** - compiled into `power1.dll` and `power2.dll` with:

- cl /EHsc /LD /W4 /DMESSAGE=power1 power.cpp /Fepower1.dll
- cl /EHsc /LD /W4 /DMESSAGE=power2 power.cpp /Fepower2.dll

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#define API __declspec(dllexport)
#define MSG1(m) #m
#define MSG(m) MSG1(m)
using namespace std;

thread* WorkerThread;
bool run;

void proc() {
    while(run) {
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(1000));
        cout << "DLL: " << MSG(MESSAGE) << endl;
    }
}

extern "C" {
API void start() {
    run = true;
    if (WorkerThread == nullptr)
        WorkerThread = new thread(proc);
}

API void stop() {
    run = false;
    WorkerThread->join();
    delete WorkerThread;
    WorkerThread = nullptr;
}
}
```

**power_main.cpp** - compiled into `power_main.exe` with:

- cl /EHsc /W4 power_main.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

typedef void (__cdecl* function_type)();

int main() {
        function_type start;
        function_type stop;
        HINSTANCE dll_handler;

        CopyFile("power1.dll", "power.dll", FALSE);
        dll_handler = LoadLibraryA("power.dll");
        start = (function_type)GetProcAddress(dll_handler, "start");
        start();

        std::cout << "Enter to FreeLibrary()...";
        getchar();
        stop = (function_type)GetProcAddress(dll_handler, "stop");
        stop();  // Comment this out to show that the DLL won't switch
        FreeLibrary(dll_handler);

        CopyFile("power2.dll", "power.dll", FALSE);
        dll_handler = LoadLibraryA("power.dll");
        start = (function_type)GetProcAddress(dll_handler, "start");
        start();

        std::cout << "Enter to FreeLibrary()...";
        getchar();
        stop = (function_type)GetProcAddress(dll_handler, "stop");
        stop();
        FreeLibrary(dll_handler);
}
```

Output:

```
Enter to FreeLibrary()...DLL: power1

DLL: power1
Enter to FreeLibrary()...DLL: power2
DLL: power2

DLL: power2
```

With `stop()` commented out:

```
Enter to FreeLibrary()...DLL: power1
DLL: power1

Enter to FreeLibrary()...DLL: power1
DLL: power1

DLL: power1
```

Comment: Jeah, I forgot to mentoin, the DLL should be "enough complex" to be able to reproduce.

We have a simple loader program and an "enough complex" DLL to reproduce the issue; tomorrow I clear the codes and bring it to you.

Comment: @user2148758 even so, this indicates that you have a reference counting issue, even though " I'm also sure there are no references to the DLL".  Every call to LoadLibrary needs a matching FreeLibrary.  You could call FreeLibrary more than once, until the DLL actually unloads, to get an idea how many references are remaining.

Comment: I added a minimal repro example.

Comment: @user2148758 The thread is running.  Did you try stopping the thread?

Comment: @user2148758 You have to stop the thread.  I added a "stop" function which joins and deletes the thread.  Before stopping, I can't delete the DLL, but after stopping I can.  std::thread is holding a reference.  It would be "bad" to unload code while a thread was executing it, don't you think?  In fact, to prove there was an extra reference before writing "stop", I just called FreeLibrary a second time and the process crashed.  That's "bad" .

Answer (score 1):

Are you *sure* the stale version in memory is used, instead of the new version on disk? The Unix (Linux) mechanism (orchestrated by `ld.so` on startup) is essentially to `mmap(3)` the shared library (the *file* referenced by the executable) into the process' virtual memory. If the file is a different one, the stale data in memory is of no use. Sure, old processes (started before the switch) will continue using the old version. Any executables that somehow link directly to the old version (i.e., not to `libxyz.so.2`, now a symlink to `libxyz.so.2.3`, but directly to old `libxyz.so.2.1.7`) will still require the obsolete version.

Comment: "Are you sure the stale version in memory is used, instead of the new version on disk?"

Yes, I see "older printouts" when calling into a "newer version of SO/DLL on disk". I can provide a minimal example if needed, just need some time to clear our codes.

"Any executables that somehow link directly to the old version ..."

Our process is not directly link to these libraries. The .SO/.DLL file is opened by `dlclose()` / `LoadLibrary()`, and of course, on Linux, it's not mentoined in `ldd programname`

Comment: @user2148758, start the program, using the old library. Stop it, replace by a new library, start again. The `dlopen(3)` call (definitely not `dlclose(3)`) *searches* for the shared library file when invoked, it can hardly link against a stale version in memory.

Comment: Stopping our program during SO/DLL update is not an option.

We are considering to move the SO/DLL loading/unloading part into a separate process as we are able to start/stop subprocesses, bit it's not an elegant solution. I'm just interested why it's not possible to forcefully unload a DLL. Tomorrow I bring a repro example.

Comment: @user2148758, then the already loaded library will stay, obviously.

Comment: I added a minimal repro example.

Answer (score 0):

@Mark Tolonen: Thank you for your answer, I appreciate it, but I'm afraid this is not what I asked.

Of course I know the thread should be stopped before unloading. Let's call this "friendly way". I intentionally didn't do that in the example I provided.

However I pointed out in the original question, and in the comment too, **we are not the development team who writes DLLs for our application**. Of course we published an SDK which contains a `stop()` function in the DLL that we call before `FreeLibrary()`. To be honest, there's a questionable amount of know-how at DLL development teams... so we don't want to rely on if the `stop()` method is implemented properly or not. I know it sounds strange but I wouldn't like to provide more info why we don't trust DLLs that are given to us.

My original question was: okey... so "friendly way" is not fulfills our Product Owner's requirements; is there a "forced way" to clear a DLL from a process? (The question title is: "Is there a way to force SO/DLL to unload from memory?") My question was theoretical: If I take the responsibility, can we do this in a "forced way"?

After days of research with my current knowledge I would say the answer is "no" - or if yes, MS hiding it very well.

Of course I understand the reasoning behind, for example, we don't want to "forcefully" stop a thread because it may holds a resource.

@Mark Tolonen: Anyway, thank you for your effort in this question. :)